# How to convert Group by to LINQ

Tags: asp.net, linq, asp.net-core

Good day. Im working on a Asp.net core ef web app and currently doing the reports using LINQ but when doing grouping by id it does not work or does not display anything, in the 1st screenshot below is the table when I only write Orderbydescending and the 2nd screenshot is the table when I write Group By.

```
public async Task<ContentResult> GetReportData() {
 
    var perAnalystReport = await  _context.Tats
        .ProjectTo<PerAnalystReportDto( _mapper.ConfigurationProvider )
        .GroupBy (x => x.CrmId )                                                                                                                         
        .OrderByDescending( x => x.Id )
        .ToListAsync();

     return Content( JsonConvert.SerializeObject( perAnalystReport ), "application/json" );
}
```

PerAnalystReporDto class

```
 public string RefNo { get; set; }
    public int CrmId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ReportDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? HoReceivedDate { get; set; }
    public string ApprovingAuthorityName { get; set; }
    public string BranchName { get; set; }
    public string AreaName { get; set; }
    public string RegionName { get; set; }
    public string Analyst { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public string RequestName { get; set; }
    public string FacilityName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string CurrencyName { get; set; }
    public int AmountFrom { get; set; }
    public int AmountTo { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string NextEntityResponsible {get; set;}
    public string Remarks { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public DateTime StatusEffectiveDate { get; set; }
    public int TatCount { get; set; }

    public int Id {get; set;}
```

Sample Tat Data

| Id | EntityResposible | Postion | Status | NextEntityResponsible | NextPosition | StatusEffectiveDate | TatCount | CrmdId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Initials | - | For Review | Sample | Analyst | 2022-11-21 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | Sample | Analyst | Returned to | Branch | - | 2022-11-21 | 0 | 1 |

[image: OrderByDescending]

[image: GroupBy]

Can Someone help me or teach me what's wrong in my code. Thank you!

Working Code:

```
public ContentResult GetReportData() {

var perAnalystReport = _context.Tats
    .ProjectTo<PerAnalystReportDto( _mapper.ConfigurationProvider )
    .ToList()
    .GroupBy (x => x.CrmId )                                                                                                                         
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending( x => x.Id ).First())
    .ToList();

 return Content( JsonConvert.SerializeObject( perAnalystReport ), "application/json" );
```

Comment: Does the above even compile? The `.GroupBy()` will return an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey,TSource>>` object, but `IGrouping<>` does not have an `Id` property. I would expect `.OrderByDescending( x => x.Id )` to throw a compile time error. `IGrouping<>` does have a `Key` property. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Yes the .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id) does not compile and gets the error that you mention, but the code above is the syntax or query that I want to display.

Comment: But when I only use the orderbydescending the code compile and display the 1st screenshot above

Comment: The CrmId has different statuses/Id and what I want is to group the data by its CrmId and only display the latest value that's why I've used GroupBy and orderbydescending but it does not work

Comment: Before we can help you, we need more information: (1) The structure of your Tats source (fields and data types). (2) Sample data. (3) The structure of your PerAnalystReportDto class. The expected results. If you can, please simplify the data to the minimum needed to demonstrate your issue. For example, include CrmId , Id, and perhaps one or two other data elements.

Comment: Hi @TN I will edit the question and post some screenshot and my codes. Thank you

Comment: Also, please expand on what you mean by "only display the latest value". Will the data contain multiple records with the same `CrmId` values, but different `Id` values? Is your intent to filter out all but one record per  `CrmId` value? Is "latest" defined by highest `Id` value (and not something like `Report Date`)?

Comment: "Will the data contain multiple records with the same CrmId values, but different Id values?" -Yes the data contains multiple records with the same CrmId but with different Id. " Is your intent to filter out all but one record per CrmId value? Is "latest" defined by highest Id value (and not something like Report Date)?" -Yes the I want to filter out all but one record per CrmId but with the highest Id  value

Comment: Please post readable data instead of screen shots, preferably as a table or code block. (If you have trouble with formatting, post what you can and someone can help tweak the layout.)

Comment: Hi @TN already done editing the post and also added the table for sample tat data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from my understanding, you want a result set that includes the top `Id` value for each `CrmId`. You were on the right track, but you needed to apply the `OrderByDescending()` withing each group and then pick just the latest (first) from within the ordered group members.

I believe the following should give you what you are looking for:

```
var perAnalystReport = await _context.Tats
    .ProjectTo<PerAnalystReportDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
    .GroupBy(x => x.CrmId )
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).First())
    .ToListAsync();
```

Or perhaps with slightly better performance:

```
var perAnalystReport = await _context.Tats
    .GroupBy(x => x.CrmId )
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).First())
    .ProjectTo<PerAnalystReportDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
    .ToListAsync();
```

The latter avoids building PerAnalystReportDto objects for records being excluded.

For the limited sample data provided, it should yield just the Id = 2 record for the CrmdId = 1 group.

Comment: Hi @TN first I want to thank you for the guidance and helping me in this problem, the code did compile but did not display any data in the table like the 2nd screenshoot of the table above

Comment: Time to dive into the debugger to examine the value of `perAnalystReport` before it is serialized. It should be a `List` of `PerAnalystReportDto` objects containing the selected data. If that looks okay, your problem may be with your report definition. Perhaps an earlier version of the code was providing the report a nested collection structure, and it is still expecting that. One way that might confirm this would be to replace the `.First()` with a `.Take(1)`. That would again generate a nested collection, and the report might display the desired data. This would only be a kluge, not a fix.

Comment: Hello @TN, I changed the code a little and it worked. Thank you for kind guidance. I'll also post the code that work for me.